# must be a nonstatic member function with typedef declared object

Tags: c++

I have set a of objects

```
struct card {
  int rank;
  int suit;
}
typedef std::pair<card, card> hand;
hand operator=(const hand& rhs);
```

I want to make a new object of type hand = to an other hand. but I get

> error: 'hand operator=(const hand&)' must be a nonstatic member
>   function

how do I make this operator nonstatic?

Comment: `operator=` must be a function inside a class, it has no meaning outside.

Comment: Sounds like what you are trying to do is this:
`hand hand;
hand second_hand(hand);`, search for copy constructor.

Comment: You cannot add `operator=` to an `std::` type, because `operator=` must be a class member and you cannot modify `std::` types. You need to find a different solution (perhaps a copy constructor as suggested in the other comment)

Comment: I didn't originally notice you were trying to assign `hand` to `hand`. You don't need to define an operator for that. `std::pair` already defines an assignment operator. The typedef is not a new type, it's just another name for an existing type. And the existing type already does what you want.